# PHP/Laravel: Why this function is being recalled?

Tags: php, laravel, function, callback

I would like to understand why this function is being called twice in laravel, I have this Factory defined:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

function my_callback (Faker $faker) { // <= LINE 5 
    return [
        // some key-value pairs, don't focus on that
        'id_ubicacion' => 1,
        'nombre' => $faker->name,
        'clase' => 'CONTROL ADMINISTRATIVO',
        'codigo' => $faker->ean13,
        // some other key-value pairs
    ];
} // <= LINE 29

$factory->define(App\Bien::class, 'my_callback');
```

then, i have the following tests:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class BienTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test__actualizar()
    {
        // setup
        $registro_a_actualizar = factory('App\Bien')->create(['id' => 1]);

        // more code...

    }

    public function test__destruir()
    {
        // setup
        $registro_a_destruir = factory('App\Bien')->create(['id' => 1]);

        // some code...
    }
```

when I execute 
    phpunit
i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_callback() 

(previously declared in \inven\database\factories\FactoryBien.php:5) 

in \inven\database\factories\FactoryBien.php on line 29
```

thanks if you can explain me: why do the function `my_callback()` is being called more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to understand how the test runner works.

Even though every test is run in what looks like a random order, that's not truly the case. Also, you have to understand that `setUp` and `tearDown` are **always** run before and after every test.

In the `setUp` method in Laravel, it'll refresh the application if the app is not running :

```
if (! $this->app) {
    $this->refreshApplication();
}
```

So we might think hey, we're keeping one instance of the app running, so we shouldn't require `ModelFactory` again, right ?

**WRONG**.

In the `tearDown` method that's called after every test, it'll actually destroy the app right before the end of the method :

```
if ($this->app) {
    foreach ($this->beforeApplicationDestroyedCallbacks as $callback) {
        call_user_func($callback);
    }

    $this->app->flush();
    $this->app = null;
}
```

That means your `ModelFactory` file is included every single time a test is run. But this happens in the same PHP process. This is why you get an already defined function error.

To prove this is easy, simply write this in your `ModelFactory` file :

```
global $a;
if (is_null($a)) {
    $a = 0;
}
else {
    $a++;
}
var_dump($a);
```

You'll see `$a` incrementing on each test running.

To fix your problem, you should simply use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) like so :

```
$factory->define(App\Bien::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        // some key-value pairs, don't focus on that
        'id_ubicacion' => 1,
        'nombre' => $faker->name,
        'clase' => 'CONTROL ADMINISTRATIVO',
        'codigo' => $faker->ean13,
        // some other key-value pairs
    ];
});
```

Comment: I shouldn't declare any function in factory files, should I?

Comment: No you shouldn't !